# Java Springboot program resulting to org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement when building

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am currently following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uLqdBpYAVA) about Spring JDBC Template, and was about to run the program for the first time (around @11:30). However, I have encountered an error and when I tried to build the project it says this:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.298 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.jdbctempl.CourseplatformApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguratio
n.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of UR
L [file:/C:/Practice/0500%20-%20Spring%20(Boot)/04_JDBCTemplate-Spring/courseplatform/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer identity NOT NULL, title varch
ar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRIMARY KEY (course_id) ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxE
rrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer [*]identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(
255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRIMARY KEY (course_id) )"; expected "ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT NULL, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON UPDATE, NOT NULL, NULL, AUTO_I
NCREMENT, DEFAULT ON NULL, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, AUTO_INCREMENT, ,, )"; SQL stat
ement:
CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRI
MARY KEY (course_id) ) [42001-214]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Practice/0500%20-%20Spring%20(Boot)/04_JDBCTemplate-Spring/courseplatform/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE course ( c
ourse_id integer identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRIMARY KEY (course_id) );
 nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer [*]identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, d
escription varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRIMARY KEY (course_id) )"; expected "ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT NULL, NULL, AS, DEFAUL
T, GENERATED, ON UPDATE, NOT NULL, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, DEFAULT ON NULL, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, NULL, CHE
CK, REFERENCES, AUTO_INCREMENT, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRI
MARY KEY (course_id) ) [42001-214]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException:
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer [*]identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRIMARY KEY (course_id) )"; expected "ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT NULL, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON UPDATE, NOT NULL, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, DEFAU
LT ON NULL, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, AUTO_INCREMENT, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE course ( course_id integer identity NOT NULL, title varchar(80) NOT NULL, description varchar(500) NOT NULL, link varchar(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRI
MARY KEY (course_id) ) [42001-214]
```

I have tried to copy his exact sql files from https://github.com/danvega/hello-jdbc but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your project must be using a version of H2 with a bug. Compare the dependency version of your H2 database with the one used in the tutorial project.

Use "mvn dependency:tree" and search for it.

Comment: The POM (https://github.com/danvega/hello-jdbc/blob/master/pom.xml) doesn't specify a JDBC version for the H2 dependency, and I'm not watching the whole of that video just to find out which version it actually uses.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a syntax issue with the script. You may use the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    course_id integer NOT NULL,
    title varchar(80) NOT NULL,         -- Course Title
    description varchar(500) NOT NULL,  -- Course Description
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL,         -- Course landing page link
    CONSTRAINT pk_course_course_id PRIMARY KEY (course_id)
);
```

Comment: That might fix the syntax error with the schema creation script, but as you're removing the `identity` functionality from the `course_id` column, could this not cause problems elsewhere? If the Java app expects IDs to be automatically generated, your change would just cause another problem later on. Would it not be better to use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` or `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` (https://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition) instead? Also, when you do post answers it's helpful to explain what change or changes you made and to which files.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I do agree on your point. But since the question was limited to the purpose of moving forward with the tutorial. I've mentioned likewise.